# Run SSIS in .Net 6 Application

Tags: c#, ssis, .net-6.0

I have created .Net 6 application that can run an SSIS package. 
Here is my code to execute the package.

```
            string pkgLocation = @"E:\UploadTask.dtsx";

            Package pkg;
            DTSExecResult pkgResults;
            Variables vars;

            Application app = new Application();
            pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);

            vars = pkg.Variables;
            vars["FilePath"].Value = destinationFileName;
            
            pkgResults = pkg.Execute();

            if (pkgResults == DTSExecResult.Success)
                Console.WriteLine("Package ran successfully");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Package failed");
```

It compiles without error, but when executed, at line "Application app = new Application();", it raises an error that says

```
error : could not load file or assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.dtsruntimewrap, version=12.0.0.0, 
culture=neutral, publickeytoken=89845dcd8080cc91'. the system cannot find the file specified.
```

Can anyone know this?

Comment: Consider running the package with SQL. It is pretty easy to to do it the package is deployed to SSISDB

Comment: Yes, I have done that. 
But now I want to try it with .net, please let me know if there is any way.

Comment: By Using SqlClient and using the same SQL.

Comment: @Priti did you find the answer? please share if you did.